# Mysql - update column from another table data without reducing rows

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join

I got stucked at the following scenario:

**table Orders**
order_id, order_date, order_customerid, order_state, order_city

**table Customers**
customer_id, customer_city, customer_state

I need to duplicate customer_city and customer_state into order_city and order_state, which is currently null. I tried using the following join:

```
select * 
from orders o
inner join customers c
on o.customerid = c.id
```

and then using an update query. But it appears to be grouping orders by customer, so then it does not reflect the actual number of orders, causing some order_city and order_state to be left empty.

What can I do to update EVERY order inside the order table, knowing that there are many orders from the same customer?

Comment: What does your entire query look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [multi-table update syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html).

Something like this would work for you:

```
update orders 
  inner join customers on customers.customer_id = orders.order_customerid 
set orders.order_state = customers.order_state, 
  orders.order_city = customers.order_city
where orders.order_state is null 
  or orders.order_city is null
```

Comment: It worked partially. I have 4090 entries in orders but it only updated 2400.
Perhaps because the grouping (ON) is not considering all orders but only the first or the last since it is grouping by customer?

Comment: I ran it again and it seems to be ok! Thanks